# Where are MAUI-created files on the Android device?

Tags: android, file, maui

From program code, I create a file on the Android device using

```
myfilestreamwriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(System.IO.Path.Combine(FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory, "myprivatefile.txt"));
myfilestreamwriter.WriteLine("some stuff");
myfilestreamwriter.Close();
```

In the above, FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory has the value

```
/data/user/0/com.mycompanyname.myprojectname/files
```

There is no issue creating the file and I am able to access and read from it later.

However, I am unable to find the folder in Windows using process 1: and in Android using process 2:.

1: Browse to the file in File Explorer on Windows

In Windows,

```
MYANDROIDDEVICE\Internal shared storage\Android\data\
```

contains a folder named

```
com.mycompanyname.myprojectname
```

and in that folder there is a single folder named

```
cache
```

but there is no sign of the file I created.

2: Browse to the file on MYANDROIDDEVICE from the Android app list using

```
Files > Android > data > com.mycompanyname.myprojectname
```

and in that folder there is a single folder named

```
cache
```

but there is no sign of the file I created.

Where is the file containing “some stuff” physically stored?

Comment: AFAIK you have to use `adb` to extract the files from the simulator/device to your desktop, unless your device is rooted

Comment: That app specfic dir is not visible on a Windows pc if your Android device is connected with a usb cable with it.

Comment: FYI: With Android Studio you have access using Device Explorer.

Comment: Also with file manager apps on your Android device you have no access.

Comment: `Where is the file containing “some stuff” physically stored?` Well that you told us: /data/user/0/com.mycompanyname.myprojectname/files

Comment: The path with the /Android/ dir is also app specific but visible on windows. But indeed your file is not there.

Comment: `Windows,

MYANDROIDDEVICE\Internal shared storage\Android\data\...` Yes but for an Android programmer on the Android device it is /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/..

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/06/storage-situation-internal-storage.html